# CRC Checksum? (Used in can open system)

Tags: crc

We want to put our own messages on a can-open system. (So we can program our own functions to the system). We can put our message on the system, but when we do this, the safety relay stops the system. (Controlled by 2 processors). We also filter out the original message with a can bridge.

Channel 1F0 and 1F1 are the the RAW inputs from the controller. (We manipulate).

We think we found the problem.
Channel 1F2 changes a sort of random, if you actuate a function. It combines the input from the other 2 input channels. It looks like this channel is used for crc safety protocol.  (Always the same output, if you combine the same multiple functions, but as there are linear controllers there are infinite combinations possible).

Anyone here who can reverse engineer what system is used for this? So we can simulatie this channel also. (Crc32 orso?).

First byte of all 3 messages is a counter. (0-8 keeps always counting).

3 Examples:

ID           DLC        Data

1F0  -       8     -        03 59 7A 7E 7F 59 7A 7E

1F1  -       8      -       03 7F 59 00 01 20 27 05

**1F2**   -      8      -       **03 0E 8E 70 1A 00 00 00**

---

1F0    -     8       -      03 59 7A 7E 7F 59 7A 7E

1F1   -      8      -       03 7F 59 03 01 20 27 05

**1F2**   -      8      -       **03 FA 3E 43 52 00 00 00**

---

1F0    -     8       -      00 59 7A 7E 7F 59 7A 7E

1F1    -     8        -     00 7F 59 02 01 20 27 05

**1F2**    -     8        -     **00 55 56 C1 C2 00 00 00**

Last 3 bytes from **1F2** (crc / checksum?) Always stays 0.

Thanks hope someone can help us.